# A weaker version of the second Hardy-Littlewood conjecture.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, prime-gaps

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $f(n)$ be the counting function for non-composite numbers.

So
$$f(0)=0,f(1)=1,f(2)=2,f(3)=3,f(4)=3,f(5)=4$$

Now my mentor noticed as a kid that apparantly

$$f(x+y) \leq f(x)+f(y) + 1$$

and he considered it intuitive.

Does this look familiar ?

Yes, it is a weaker version of the famous second Hardy- Littlewood conjecture :

Let $\pi(x)$ be the prime counting function. The second Hardy- Littlewood conjecture states that $\pi(x+y) \leq \pi(x) + \pi(y)$, $x,y \geq 2$.

So we get the variation "conjecture T":

$\pi(x+y) \leq \pi(x) + \pi(y) + 2$

Now you are maybe thinking, so what ? Just a random conjecture ? Nothing special ?

But now comes the question.

It is known that :

The statement of the second Hardy–Littlewood conjecture is equivalent to the statement that the number of primes from x + 1 to x + y is always less than or equal to the number of primes from 1 to y. This was proved to be inconsistent with the first Hardy–Littlewood conjecture on prime k-tuples, and the first violation is expected to likely occur for very large values of x.[2][3] For example, an admissible k-tuple (or prime constellation) of 447 primes can be found in an interval of y = 3159 integers, while π(3159) = 446.

See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture

So I wonder :

Is conjecture T still consistant with the first Hardy–Littlewood conjecture ?

How much do we need to make the second Hardy–Littlewood conjecture weaker to be consistant with the first Hardy–Littlewood conjecture ?

Comment: It has been proposed that the correct conjecture would be $\pi(x+y)-\pi(x) \le 2\pi(\frac y2)$ ("the interval from $-\frac y2$ to $\frac y2$ contains the most primes").

Comment: "the counting function for non-composite numbers." Isn't this simply the prime counting function with a shift by $1$ ?

Comment: @GregMartin is that $y$ the largest or smallest ?

Comment: @Peter yes that is true.

Comment: @GregMartin proposed where ? by who ? when ?

Comment: The idea is already present in [Richards's paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1974-80-03/S0002-9904-1974-13434-8/S0002-9904-1974-13434-8.pdf) that shows that the two Hardy–Littlewood conjectures are incompatible.